# is there any example of function that has no side effect but non-referential transparency?

Tags: side-effects

I know side effect and non-referential transparency mean different thing.
 "side effect, which implies some violation of referential transparency." 
"Referential transparency means that an expression (such as a function call) can be replaced with its value; "

However, I wonder if there is any example of function that has no side effect but non-referential transparency
If yes, would anyone give me an example (e.g. in C function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking:

> I wonder if there is any example of function that has no side effect but non-referential transparency If yes, would anyone give me an example

Here is an example:

```
int globalValue = 0;

 int f(int x)
 {
   globalValue++;
   return x + globalValue;
 }

 int g(int x)
 {
   return x + globalValue;
 }
// assuming the compiler orders the methods to execute from top to bottom
int p = f(1) + // f(1) == 2 , globalValue == 1 : side effect
        g(1) + // g(1) == 2 , globalValue == 1 : no side effect
        f(1) + // f(1) == 3 , globalValue == 2 : side effect
        g(1);  // g(1) == 3 , globalValue == 2 : no side effect
```

In this example `f` performs a side-effect and it is not referentially transparent, while `g` **does not** perform a side-effect, but it is non-referentially transparent as well (since the two calls of `g(1)` produces two different values).

Answer (score 2):

Consider a function that interrogates the external environment, eg returns the current time, or the free space on your hard disk, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Referential transparency implies no side effects: if you can *replace* a function with the value it returns there can be no side effects: The function can only compute a value based on the values passed to it.

The statement "side effect implies no referential transparency" is just the contrapositive of the above and logically equivalent to it.

Comment: so can you give an example of function that has no side effect but non-referential transparency?

Comment: What if there is a side effect that you cannot observe, would that be good enough?

Comment: so what if I change to question to "no FUNCTIONAL side effect but  non-referential transparency"?